# How to append new items to KeyValuePair saved in text file in C#

Tags: c#

- I'm generating book serial no's and saving to keyvalue pair which
  then save to text file, each key is unique.
- when I save it to text file, the key is generated and I can retrieve the key and it works fine.
- When I generate second key, and save it to the text file, it over-writes the text file and previously generated key gets deleted.

**Generating Keys:**

```
private void GenerateButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                BookcomboBox2.Items.Clear();

                from = int.Parse(FrmtextBox1.Text);
                to = int.Parse(TotextBox2.Text);

                result = to - from;

                for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++)
                {
                    string item = Convert.ToString(from + i); 
                    BookcomboBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, item)); // 
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Book No 1,  Generated Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                BookcomboBox2.Items.Clear();

                from = int.Parse(FrmtextBox1.Text);
                to = int.Parse(TotextBox2.Text);

                result = to - from;

                for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++)
                {
                    string item = Convert.ToString(from + i);
                    BookcomboBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, item)); // CatA has 0 key value
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Book No-2 Generated Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

**Saving Keys**

```
private void Savebutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Books.txt")))
            {

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals);
                sw.Write(json);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Books Saved Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
```

**When I add new book, afterwards and save, instead to append with Book-2 it overwrites the file with book-2 only, previously created book-1 gets deleted.**

p.s: if the question sounds confusing, please ask.

**Edited**

**solution given by patrick is working but it's giving me this error when reading it again:**

[image: ERROR]

when I checked the file I noticed this:

[image: Append]

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: put a breakpoint on 

`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals);`

what is the content of vals, when your second writing is started?

Comment: vals contains 1st book. when the second is added, and re-write vals, 1st gets deleted second book remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a correct solution to this question!

Read this text carefully:

> > Assuming that you have to add users to an existing JSON file, the
> >     basic approach is:
>
> - > Read / parse JSON file to get an in-memory data structure
>
> > - Modify the data structure to add the users.
>
> - > Unparse / write the data structure to a new copy of the file.
> - > There is no way to do update-in-place on a JSON file.

From: [How to write to a JSON file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536818/how-to-write-to-a-json-file-using-c)

Basically You will Deserialize your EXACTLY same dictionary on which you added items.

I have added this code on the top of "Generate Button" before generating I'm deserializing my exising file and adding back to same dictionary on which I'm going to add new items "Variable name should be exactly same!"

```
     if (File.Exists("Books.txt"))
            {
                string jsonToRead = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Books.txt"));
                vals =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>(jsonToRead);
            }
```

**In this way, I'm loading my existing data from text file and re-writing with new data. That's it!.**

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `File.CreateText()` will overwrite the file, if it already exists.

If you want to append to an existing file, you could use `new StreamWriter(path, append: true)` instead

Comment: this is working, but it's giving me error when I'm reading it again, please check my edited question.

Comment: Problem with this answer is: it appends the key value pair at the end of the array, instead of putting inside the array which throws up the error, "Additional text encountered after reading JSON Content [. This will not work when you want to read data again, as it is creating something like this.
`[{Array1}] <-- FOR JSON HERE you hit the end, it will throw up error that I found this -- > " [ " -- > [Array2]`